# registerReceiver returns null for SCAN_RESULTS_AVAILABLE_ACTION

Tags: android, android-wifi

I'm trying to get the available Wifi list.

I have a separate class that holds the receiver.

```
public  BroadcastReceiver WifiScanBroadcast = new BroadcastReceiver(){
    public void onReceive(Context context, android.content.Intent intent) 
    {
        results = wifiManager.getScanResults();
        size = results.size();
    };
```

I have instantiated the class with the variable wifiManager.
Thats the onCreate function of my Activity:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_wifi_list);
    wifiManager = new WifiApManager(this);

    Intent i = registerReceiver(wifiManager.WifiScanBroadcast, new IntentFilter(WifiManager.SCAN_RESULTS_AVAILABLE_ACTION));


}
```

This is what i use in the manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
```

When I'm getting to the registerReceiver, it returns Null.
What is wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't really get what was wrong with my code, but moving to receiver to 
the activity(in the past the receiver was declared in another class) solved the problem.
Now it works

Answer (score 0):

Read the [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#registerReceiver): The first sticky intent found that matches filter, or null if there are none.

Comment: I've read it. I understand that my filter might be not correct. 
 All the examples i found use SCAN_RESULTS_AVAILABLE_ACTION. What should i use then?